# Condenser fan and compressor don't start, electrical looks good though?

Tags: air-conditioning, compressor, relay

After replacing the fan, starting capacitor, and running capacitor, the system ran normally for ~1 day. Now nothing is starting.

I got a fieldpiece multimeter and tested all of new capacitors, connections, motor ohms, continuity, and current. All measurements look good, but current isn't flowing more than 0.05a, and capacitors don't seem to be charging.

There is 240v going to it, not sure what else to attempt, any suggestions are welcome.

Goodman gx160481fa

Comment: contacts burned/oxidized/rusted in the contactor or terminal block?

Comment: Can you trace the 240V through to the compressor motor windings with R hotwired to Y at the 'stat?

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be that you should have called an HVAC company first since this is what they are "schooled" in. I have to ask,  why did you replace the fan and compressor capacitors? Were they bad or were you just guessing on a repair effort. When you say 240 is going to it, what do you mean? Where are you measuring the 240 volts. Is it at the incoming power supply or at the starter/contactor going to the compressor? Is the contactor energizing? Do you have 24 volts at the coil of the contactor? Is the fan running in the indoor air handler? The problem could be a tripped circuit breaker or blown fuse (now showing my age),at the 24 volt power source. Please call someone familiar with A/C service before you do something you can"t fix. These units can hurt you. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to all who had replied, I did not have a chance to check until now. I'm in Houston where we just had Harvey, 1" more and the water would've been inside my home, I was very lucky. With the floods there have been many power outages, on/off a lot, surges, etc. I think those may have caused damage to the unit. My background is in Physics, I know electronics well enough to have taken a stab at diagnosing/repairing without getting zapped, just had to brush up on industry standards/lingo.

The original fan and starter capacitor were indeed bad and I was lucky to find them locally at a store which was both open and sold retail, very many only sell to contractors.

On my 3rd or 4th turn of re-checking everything, just in case I wasn't thinking straight sitting in the sun, I noticed one of the lines was giving 120V while the other was only at 40V. I don't know how in the world that could've been, I do know that I saw both at 120V before.

I then went over to the main fuse panel and flipped everything going to the house off, waited a while as I went to help a neighbor with flood-related demo work, then came back. Flipping the fuses back on gave 120V to both lines and it kicked on. Still running.